# Is $A-B ⊆ P(A-B)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let

$A =\{x\mid x = k^2 \text{ where $k ∈ N$ and $k \le 20$}\}$

$B = \{x ∈ \mathbb{Z}^+ \mid \text{$x$ is an odd and $x \le 9$}\} $

**Is $A-B ⊆ P(A-B)$?**

From what I get

$A = \{0,1,4,9,16\}$

$B = \{1,3,5,7,9\}$

Thus,

$A-B =\{0,4,16\}$

$P(A-B) = \{\varnothing,\{0\},\{4\},\{16\},\{0,4\},\{0,16\},\{4,16\},\{0,4,16\}\}$

Base on my understanding, a power set $P(S)$ of a set S is the set of all subsets of $S$, but how about this one?

**Is $A-B ⊆ P(A-B)$?**

Answer (score 1):

Not in general, no, and not in your case.

Elements of $A-B$ are *numbers*, that is, $A-B\subseteq \mathbb N$.

On the other hand, elements of $P(A-B)$ are *sets of numbers*, and sets of numbers are not numbers - they are not elements of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Very clear and nice! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

No, because $P(A-B)$ contains sets while $A-B$ contains "regular" elements (elements which are not sets). Therefore for example, $0\in A-B$ however $0$ is not an element of $P(A-B)$.

Please notice the difference between $0$ and $\{0\}$.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am confused with !! Thank yo very much!